# Using phpmailer to send a message

Tags: php, html, email, phpmailer

I'm trying to make a registration page by sending an activation email, but I get this error using phpmailer:

```
Warning: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed in C:\xampp\htdocs\Exercicis\M08+M09\phpmailer\class.smtp.php on line 269
```

I have already searched a lot of information but I have not found anything to solve it 
My code:

```
<?php  
$usuario = $_POST['uname'];
$passwrod = $_POST['psw1'];
$correo = $_POST['email'];
include('phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');
include('phpmailer/class.smtp.php');
$password = rand(1999, 9999);   
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->Username = 'example@gmail.com';
$mail->Password = 'secret';
$mail->From = 'example@gmail.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Administrador PHP';
$mail->Subject = 'Subject del Email';
$mail->AltBody = 'Password: "'. $password .'"';
$mail->AltBody = 'Registrat: http://localhost:3000/Practica/panell_reg.php';
$mail->MsgHTML('Registrat: http://localhost:3000/Practica/panell_reg.php<br>Password: "'. $password .'"<br>.');
$mail->AddAddress($correo);
//$mail->SMTPDebug = 4;
$mail->IsHTML(true);

if(!$mail->Send()) {
      echo 'Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
      echo 'Mensaje enviado correctamente';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

PHP 5.6 verifies SSL certificates by default, and if there is a problem relating to certificate you will get this error. The correct solution is to fix your SSL config. You can read about this error in the toubleshooting docs for PHPMailer https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting?